# Algorithm For Finding All Possible Sums for an Arbitrary Positive Integer, n?:

Tags: algorithms

Is there a known algorithm to find all possible sets of positive integers such that the sum over each set equals an arbitrary integer, n?

Plainly, is there a known algorithm to find A:

$n\in N,A, B\subset N,B\in A, b\in B < n:$

$\forall B\in A:\sum_{b\in B} b=n$

?

I have searched for such an algorithm, but to no avail.

For example:

For $n=3:$
$A={{1,1,1],{1,2}}

Comment: Yes, there is an obvious recursive algorithm: the largest element in any solution is somewhere between 1 and n. Drop that element, and complete recursively. By the way, you forgot the solution {3} in your example.

Comment: This is unsuitable for MathOverflow. Ask on math.stackexchange.  Also, you might try searching for "partitions of an integer" first; the number of partitions for something like 200 is  more than a trillion, if memory serves.  So if you do implement an algorithm, you should be prepared to use it only for small inputs, perhaps n < 50.  One recursive algorithm uses a subroutine like part(m,k) which returns the list of partitions of m into parts where each part has size at least k.  Implement that carefully, and the rest will be easy. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.17

Comment: I don't mean to ask a silly question, but why do you feel that this is inappropriate on MathOverflow and not on Math.StackExchange? They seem very similar.
Obviously, do to complexity, I would be unable to use this for large n, but I am asking if an algorithm already exists, rather than whether it would be 'useful' for large n or not.

In addition: I feel that searching for: "partitions of an integer" may help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Zéychin: please read the FAQ. MathOverflow is for **research-level** questions only. Given that partitions are routinely covered in the first half of an undergraduate curriculum, your question is obviously not suitable here.

Comment: It appears that you have contradicted yourself between your comment here and your comment on 'Ross J's answer. Please verify your stance on my inquiry and reply again.

Comment: Zeychin, MathOverflow is intended to be a forum for research mathematicians with topics for that level.  Your question concerns a topic that is outside that scope.  You also have been given some pointers and resources to pursue regarding your question, as opposed to just being told to go to math.stackexchange.  If you come back with the intent that you think your questions are in the scope of this forum,and you are wrong, you will not be treated as well as you have been.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.19 

Comment: @Zéychin: No I have not. The point of my comment was that saying "look up partitions of n" was not really helpful enough (and then Ross J modified his answer to point to actual algorithms). None of this changes the fact that the question is inappropriate for MO.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $n$. Here are some [algorithms](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ivan/F49-int-part.pdf).

Comment: No it's not, not really. The partitions of n counts *how many* such sets the algorithm should find.

Comment: @Thierry: That is a different convention, and it is also correct to use the term “partition of n” to refer to each way to write n as a sum of positive integers.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: you're right, of course. Though if the OP looks for "partitions of n", they will find mostly material on how to count them, rather than algorithms to produce them.